# Month and Year not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to display the current month and year, but nothing is being displayed.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="date"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#date {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
(function() {
    var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

    var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

    Date.prototype.getMonthName = function() {
        return months[ this.getMonth() ];
    };
    Date.prototype.getDayName = function() {
        return days[ this.getDay() ];
    };
})();

var now = new Date();

var day = now.getDayName();
var month = now.getMonthName();
```

Comment: Why do you have days when you want the current month and year?

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect your JS to your HTML. This is done via the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/DOM).

First, you need to get the Date div, then use your day and month values to insert the data into the div.

Add these two lines to the bottom of your JS, and you'll see the date and month.

```
var date_div = document.getElementById("date")
date_div.innerHTML = day + "," + month
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = month;

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for?

```js
(function() {

  var date = new Date();

  var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

  var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

  document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = months[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + months[date.getDay()]
})();
```

```css
#date {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even use

```
document.querySelector("#date").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",day+","+month)
```

but be careful this will not clear the already available content in the date div

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please try this is the working code.

JS

```
(function() {
    var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

    var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

    Date.prototype.getMonthName = function() {
        return months[ this.getMonth() ];
    };
    Date.prototype.getDayName = function() {
        return days[ this.getDay() ];
    };
})();

var now = new Date();
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = now.getDayName() + "-" +  now.getMonthName();
```

Html

```
<div id="date"></div>
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5w409esy/1/)