# DIV not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm wondering why my DIV would not show up.  No errors pop up in the console so I'm not sure what is the problem.  I also checked the Content Security Policy for Google Chrome Extensions to see if my code didn't follow the policy, but everything seems to be fine.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="date"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
(function() {
    var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

    var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

    Date.prototype.getMonthName = function() {
        return months[ this.getMonth() ];
    };
    Date.prototype.getDayName = function() {
        return days[ this.getDay() ];
    };
})();

var now = new Date();

var day = now.getDayName();
var month = now.getMonthName();
```

**CSS:**

```
#date {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Your div is there, it's just empty *(no width, height, or text)* and has nothing to do with that JavaScript.

Comment: Where exactly is the content you're expecting your `div` to contain coming from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Month and Year not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57139093/month-and-year-not-displaying)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to populate your date div in order for it to show something. Empty divs don't take up any space. I've used innerHTML to move the day and month variables into the element:

```js
(function() {
  var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

  var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

  Date.prototype.getMonthName = function() {
    return months[this.getMonth()];
  };
  Date.prototype.getDayName = function() {
    return days[this.getDay()];
  };
})();

var now = new Date();

var day = now.getDayName();
var month = now.getMonthName();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = day + " " + month;
```

```css
#date {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```

Comment: I got an error "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" when I used innerHTML, do you have any advice?

Comment: That happens when either the element (div with ID of "date") doesn't exist in the DOM, or there is a mistake (typo) when you are attempting to get the element in JavaScript. Did you use the first part of the statement that has the document.getElementById("date")? Also, is this div element created in your HTML markup, or do you add it later through JavaScript?

Comment: I used the first part of the statement that has the document.getElementById("date"), and the div element is created in my HTML markup.

Comment: I was able to fix the bug because by moving my script source below the div.  Thank you for your time and help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to inject the date into the div.

Try something like this:

```js
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = now;
```